# Object of type function is not JSON serializable in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have been trying to pass this data in json format but i keep getting this error. I am getting all the data and passing it to a payment getaway for processing. But anytime I pass the data i get the error message. Below is the trace message i am getting.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robert Yenji\Envs\bob\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Robert Yenji\Envs\bob\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\New folder (2)\project\votedigital\vote\views.py", line 903, in paytes
    data = json.dumps({
  File "c:\python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "c:\python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "c:\python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "c:\python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

```
def paytes(request): 
    amount = 10
    desc = "USSD"
    category = 'Robert'
    phone = "233244491909"
    vote = "10"
    slug = "test"
    award = "test"
    url = 'https://api.pays.co/charge'
    transaction_id = random.randint(100000000000, 999999999999)
    data = json.dumps({
        "reference": transaction_id,
        "amount": amount,
        "phone": phone,
        "email":"customer@gmail.com",
        "mobile_money": {
        "phone" : "0244496709",
        "provider" : "MTN"
         },
        "label" : desc,
        "metadata":{
            "custom_fields": [
                {
                    "value": desc,
                    "nominee_name": slug,
                    "transaction_id": transaction_id,
                    "amount": amount,
                    "award": award,
                    "category": category,
                    "email": email,
                    "phone": phone,
                    "vote": vote,
                }
            ]
        } 
})
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer texk_002929992',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: What is the `text` variable set to?

Comment: Also, could you post the full traceback instead of just the end?

Comment: @pigrammer posted

Comment: It appears that one of the variables that you don't define here and/or that you define here but is different in  your real code is actually a function that you forgot to call (or is not meant to be a function). Look through your code and/or use a debugger to find out which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

Tried dumping your data and it gave me the error "name email is not defined". Changing it to some string solves the issue. So most probably it is an auto import or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Email is not defined

```
amount = 10
desc = "USSD"
category = 'Robert'
phone = "233244491909"
vote = "10"
slug = "test"
award = "test"
url = 'https://api.pays.co/charge'
```

"email": email,